# I have a Program.cs file. Can I recreate my project in Visual Studio with just this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Program.cs file. Can I recreate my project in Visual Studio with just this?
Is this possible? If so, can you please help me do it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can always create a new project and use your existing `Program.cs` file.

Comment: is all your code inside that file?

Comment: Well, as a .cs file is not a project, no. You *can*, however, create a new project and use your existing file in that project.

Comment: rcs: How?
Hybridzz: I'm not quite sure. It's just the program.cs file that was in the folder my old program got saved to (I lost the slv file and all). I'm new to this, sorry.

Comment: @KenWhite I thought I could do that so I used it with the `File>New>Project From existing code` function, but now there are 2 errors I've never seen before. It seems like something's missing.

Comment: Well yeah, you will have to understand and resolve those errors.  Why don't you tell us what they are?

Comment: I just don't know how to rewrite the code as I got some help with it and that person isn't able to help me anymore. I see the code is in the Program.cs file that's why I asked.

Comment: Error #1:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. test1

Comment: Error #2: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. test1

Comment: I see that it says "To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.", but I don't know what this means. Could someone explain it to me, please?

Comment: You are targeting .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile.  You need to install the SDK to continue.

Comment: Huh, I could've sworn I had it. Oh well. Could you tell me the difference between the different framework versions?

Comment: Try googling "differences between .net framework versions"

Comment: I went to install the sdk, but it said .Net Framework 4.0 or higher was already installed so it didn't install. I went to retry the build and it still came up with these errors. @Amy

Comment: .Net Framework 4.0 is different from .Net Framework 4.0 *Client Profile*

Comment: Oh yeah! Haha sorry, brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to recreate the whole solution or project, but you can add the existing code to a new project. Information such as references, target framework, and more will be lost.